# Call variable within class from another variable

Tags: php, oop

I have the following code:

```
<?php
class myclass {
    public $var;
    public $foo = $this->var;
}
// ...etc
```

When I execute this, I get the following error:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in
>   E:\public_html\index.php on line 4

How can I call this variable **not** outside of class? (I mean, I don't want to define it like the following):

```
$myclass = new myclass();
$myclass->foo = $myclass->var;
```

Comment: In the constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class variables can only be defined with constant values.

To make a dynamic assignment, you need to do it in your constructor:

```
class myclass {
    public $var = "Hey there";
    public $foo;

    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->foo = $this->var;
    }
}
```

Once you create an instance of this class `$foo` will have a value of "Hey there".

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> Class member variables are called "properties". You may also see them referred to using other terms such as "attributes" or "fields", but for the purposes of this reference we will use "properties". They are defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private, followed by a normal variable declaration. This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

Comment: Doesn't serve much purpose if `$var` itself doesn't have/get a value, though.

Comment: @Jeto Clearly. =) Which the same as his original code example. I'm just answering the question at hand here. But I updated to make that more clear anyway.